# Spring-Boot JPA - Inserting into DB with foreign keys in JSON RequestBody results in null object

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm attempting to save records to a database table that includes a foreign key to another table using Spring-Boot and Spring Data JPA.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "requestId": 10080,
    "auditType": "C",
    "auditDate": "2019-06-12T17:25:43.511",
    "auditUsername": "cdunstal",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eget porttitor velit. Fusce libero augue, tincidunt in vestibulum nec, lobortis tristique eros. Cras tempor est magna, eu dapibus metus bibendum non.",
    "isReportable": "Y"
}
```

My Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHANGE_AUDIT")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CHANGE_AUDIT_PK_SEQ", sequenceName = "CHANGE_AUDIT_PK_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class ChangeAudit {

    @Column(name = "AUDIT_ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CHANGE_AUDIT_PK_SEQ")
    private Integer id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_ID")
    @NotNull
    private ChangeRequest changeRequest;

    @Column(name = "AUDIT_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 1)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 1)
    private String auditType;

    @Column(name = "AUDIT_DATE", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Date auditDate;

    @Column(name = "AUDIT_USER", nullable = false, length = 10)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    private String auditUsername;

    @Column(name = "AUDIT_MESSAGE", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 4000)
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "IS_REPORTABLE", nullable = false, length = 1)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 1)
    private String isReportable;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted.
}
```

My Controller method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changeAudit/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody()
public ChangeAudit createChangeAudit(@RequestBody ChangeAudit changeAudit) {
    logger.info("Creating new ChangeAudit: " + changeAudit.toString());
    return this.changeAuditService.createChangeAudit(changeAudit);
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1560412164364,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException",
    "message": "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction",
    "path": "/grade-admin-api/changeAudit/create"
}
```

Which is caused by:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:87)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [au.edu.csu.gradeadmin.api.entity.ChangeAudit] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=changeRequest, rootBeanClass=class au.edu.csu.gradeadmin.api.entity.ChangeAudit, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
```

So, when saving the `ChangeAudit`, it's not taking the `requestId` from the JSON and translating that to the `ChangeRequest` object in the Entity.

I can't seem to find any documentation or tutorial or any other stack overflow question that solves my problem. I have tried using a different class as the `@RequestBody` but it just comes back with null values. I've been stuck on this for two days and need to get passed it, so would appreciate any assistance anyone might be able to offer.

Forgive the brevity, I had to rush the posting. Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

**Update - Answer**

@user06062019 put me on the right track. I corrected the submitted JSON and added the CascadeType.ALL to the Entity, however, this gave me a different error - that I couldn't insert null into ChangeRequest.pidm.

This is because I had requestId as the foreign key in the submitted JSON, however, it needed to be just id, which is what the parameter in the ChangeRequest class is called. I could then retrieve the ChangeRequest class in the ChangeAuditService, add it to the ChangeAudit object and save it. Voila!

Correct JSON:

```
{
    "changeRequest": {
        "id": 10080 
    },
    "auditType": "C",
    "auditDate": "2019-06-12T17:36:43.511",
    "auditUsername": "someuser",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eget porttitor velit. Fusce libero augue, tincidunt in vestibulum nec, lobortis tristique eros. Cras tempor est magna, eu dapibus metus bibendum non.",
    "isReportable": "Y"
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the method as how you save the entity.Exception says changeRequest should not be null.You might need to set the changeRequest object to the entity before saving.

Comment: Either the `ChangeRequest` should already exist in DB or you need to get the `ChangeRequest` object and set it in `ChangeAudit` before persisting.

Comment: @Suresh I know, that's what I can't achieve. I can't figure out how to get the `ChangeAudit` object from the foreign key (`requestId`)

Comment: @user06062019 I haven't written a ControllerAdvice class yet. The error is from the built in error processing/validation from the `@NotNull` annotation in the Entity. –

Comment: @Cyntech does changeAudit.toString() prints the requestId?  Create a ChangeRequest repository which represents your ChangeRequest entity.If the requestId is null it means that the entity does not exists in the database and can handle the error.In another case,when requestId is not null call the ChangeRequest repository's findById and get the entity object,set this entity object to the ChangeAudit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is issue in the json which you are sending to the

```
createChangeAudit
```

The ChangeAudit object expects an object type for the ChangeRequest and that object type is missing in the request json.

So if you change your request to something like this it should not complain about the validation error and rest will be taken care by the spring-data automagic .

```
{

    "auditType": "C",
    "auditDate": "2019-06-12T17:25:43.511",
    "auditUsername": "cdunstal",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eget porttitor velit. Fusce libero augue, tincidunt in vestibulum nec, lobortis tristique eros. Cras tempor est magna, eu dapibus metus bibendum non.",
    "isReportable": "Y",
    "changeRequest":{
        "requestId": 10080
    }


}
```

Also you might need to mention on @ManyToOne mapping with cascade= CascadeType.ALL