# How to fix "Entities/Tables Relationship" in a Spring Boot Application connected with a postgreSQL (Problem in POST Request)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot Application connected with a PostgreSQL, I have a problem with two of my Classes. User.Class and Vehicle.Class. When I try to make a POST Request from Postman in order to create a new Vehicle I cannot generate a FK in the Vehicles TABLE in the Database. I think that maybe I have a problem with the declaration of the OneToMany Relationship in these two Entities.

User.Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "vehicleproject")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "afm")
private int afm;

@Column(name = "role_id")
private UserType type;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = Vehicle.class)
private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

public User(){}

public User(long id, String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String address, int afm, UserType type, List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.type = type;
    this.vehicles = vehicles;
}

public User(long id, String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String address, int afm, UserType type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.type = type;
    this.vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}

public User(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String address, int afm, UserType type) {

    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.type = type;
    this.vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}


public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
    return vehicles;
}

public void setVehicles(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {

    this.vehicles = vehicles;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getAfm() {
    return afm;
}

public void setAfm(int afm) {
    this.afm = afm;
}

public UserType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(UserType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void addVehicleToList(Vehicle vehicle){
    this.vehicles.add(vehicle);
}

public void removeVehicleFromUserList(Vehicle vehicle){
    this.vehicles.remove(vehicle);
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", afm=" + afm +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", vehicles=" + vehicles +
            '}';
}
```

}

Vehicle.Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicles", schema = "vehicleproject")
public class Vehicle {

@Id
@Column(name = "vehicle_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "brand")
private String brand;

@Column(name = "model")
private String model;

@Column(name = "creation_date")
private LocalDate creationDate;

@Column(name = "color")
private String color;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
private User user;

@Column(name = "plate_number")
private String plateNumber;

public Vehicle(){
}


public Vehicle(long id, String brand, String model, LocalDate creationDate, String color, User user, String plateNumber) {
    this.id = id;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.color = color;
    this.user = user;
    this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
}

public Vehicle(String brand, String model, LocalDate creationDate, String color, User user, String plateNumber) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.color = color;
    this.user = user;
    this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
}

public Vehicle(long id, String brand, String model, LocalDate creationDate, String color, String plateNumber) {
    this.id = id;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.color = color;
    this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
}

public String getPlateNumber() {
    return plateNumber;
}

public void setPlateNumber(String plateNumber) {
    this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public LocalDate getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(LocalDate creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}


@JsonIgnore
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

@JsonProperty
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle) o;
    return id == vehicle.id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Vehicle{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", brand='" + brand + '\'' +
            ", model='" + model + '\'' +
            ", creationDate=" + creationDate +
            ", color='" + color + '\'' +
            ", user=" + user +
            ", plateNumber='" + plateNumber + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

SQL TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE vehicleproject.vehicles (
    vehicle_id serial NOT NULL,
    brand varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    model varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    creation_date date NULL,
    color varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    plate_number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT vehicle_pkey PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id),
    CONSTRAINT vehicle_plate_number_key UNIQUE (plate_number),
    CONSTRAINT vehicle_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES 
vehicleproject.users(user_id)
);



CREATE TABLE vehicleproject.users (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NULL,
    "password" varchar(255) NULL,
    first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    afm int8 NULL,
    role_id int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_email_key UNIQUE (email),
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT user_role_code_fkey FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES 
vehicleproject.roles(role_code) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I try to do a POST REQUEST FROM POSTMAN, for example:

```
{
    "brand": "OPEL",
    "model": "KALIBRA",
    "creationDate": "2015-05-05",
    "color": "WHITE",
    "plateNumber": "AAA2222",
    "user_id":"2"
}
```

But in the Vehicles TABLE I take a "NULL" in "user_id" COLUMN and in IntelliJ I take this message:

```
2019-06-17 19:43:25.907  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core 
{5.3.9.Final}
2019-06-17 19:43:25.912  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties 
not found
2019-06-17 19:43:26.104  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons 
Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-06-17 19:43:26.335  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2019-06-17 19:43:26.637  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual 
LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2019-06-17 19:43:26.645  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration 
[java.util.UUID] overrides previous : 
org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@424f02b8
2019-06-17 19:43:27.513  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA 
EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-06-17 19:43:28.181  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 
'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-17 19:43:28.227  WARN 12848 --- [           main] 
aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is 
enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during 
view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable 
this warning
2019-06-17 19:43:28.541  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 
(http) with context path ''
2019-06-17 19:43:28.547  INFO 12848 --- [           main] 
c.a.v.VehicleRepairShopApplication       : Started 
VehicleRepairShopApplication in 6.402 seconds (JVM running for 7.474)
2019-06-17 19:44:12.403  INFO 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C. 
[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet ' 
dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-17 19:44:12.403  INFO 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 
'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-17 19:44:12.417  INFO 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 13 
ms
2019-06-17 19:44:12.642 DEBUG 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        vehicleproject.vehicles
        (brand, color, creation_date, model, plate_number, user_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-06-17 19:44:12.646 TRACE 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as 
[VARCHAR] - [OPEL]
2019-06-17 19:44:12.646 TRACE 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as 
[VARCHAR] - [WHITE]
2019-06-17 19:44:12.650 TRACE 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [DATE] 
- [2015-05-05]
2019-06-17 19:44:12.650 TRACE 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as 
[VARCHAR] - [KALIBRA]
2019-06-17 19:44:12.650 TRACE 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as 
[VARCHAR] - [AAA2222]
2019-06-17 19:44:12.650 TRACE 12848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as 
[BIGINT] - [null]
```

I see the problem in the last line but I cant fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you have JSON, and you have an entity. What is the code in between, that reads and parses the JSON, then creates and populates a Vehicle (and in particular, its `user` property? That's where the problem is: if you never initialize vehicle.user, then it's null, and so null is inserted in the column which maps this user property.

Comment: May be you can check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56575939/spring-boot-jpa-inserting-into-db-with-foreign-keys-in-json-requestbody-result/56584629#56584629

Comment: How can I initialize it in my code? This is that I cannot understand...

Comment: You might need to change the mapping and put cascade type all

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

cascade = CascadeType.ALL was the Solution. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @user06062019 you are right! This is the solution. Thanks a lot my friend!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this link[Creating linked entity using rest-spring-data-hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56575939/spring-boot-jpa-inserting-into-db-with-foreign-keys-in-json-requestbody-result/56584629#56584629)

It seems you are missing CascadeType.ALL which will result in saving the entity.